Looking for someone who can vouch a web3 crypto game to @blowfishxyz
I'm working on a small Web3 game, but I've discovered that it's been blocked by Blowfish. The game app is almost ready, able deposit and withdraw my SPL token in devnet. I was advised to find a reputable developer to vouch for me. I've already reached out to several communities, including the Solana Community Discord and Reddit. If anyone could kindly assist me or point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance!
